# MySQL append json object to array of json objects

Tags: mysql, json

In this table - `foo_table` i have a column - `foo_ids` and its content is as follows: 
`[{"id": "432"}, {"id": "433"}]`

my question is there a way to append new json object to this column?
so for example if i have this new object - `{"id": "554"}` i want my `foo_ids` column value to become - 
 
`[{"id": "432"}, {"id": "433"}, {"id": "554"}]`

any idea how can i insert if nothing exists and append new json object if already exists?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_ARRAY_APPEND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append) function as follows:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `foo_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo_table` (
    ->   `id` SERIAL,
    ->   `foo_ids` JSON
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `foo_table` (`foo_ids`)
    -> VALUES (NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `foo_ids`
    -> FROM `foo_table`;
+----+---------+
| id | foo_ids |
+----+---------+
|  1 | NULL    |
+----+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `foo_table`
    -> SET `foo_ids` = IF(
    ->                     `foo_ids` IS NULL OR
    ->                     JSON_TYPE(`foo_ids`) != 'ARRAY',
    ->                     JSON_ARRAY(),
    ->                     `foo_ids`
    ->                   ),
    ->     `foo_ids` = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(
    ->                   `foo_ids`,
    ->                   '$',
    ->                   CAST('{"id": "432"}' AS JSON),
    ->                   '$',
    ->                   CAST('{"id": "433"}' AS JSON)
    ->                 )
    -> WHERE `id` = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`, `foo_ids`
    -> FROM `foo_table`;
+----+--------------------------------+
| id | foo_ids                        |
+----+--------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"id": "432"}, {"id": "433"}] |
+----+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `foo_table`
    -> SET `foo_ids` = IF(
    ->                     `foo_ids` IS NULL OR
    ->                     JSON_TYPE(`foo_ids`) != 'ARRAY',
    ->                     JSON_ARRAY(),
    ->                     `foo_ids`
    ->                   ),
    ->     `foo_ids` = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(
    ->                   `foo_ids`,
    ->                   '$',
    ->                   CAST('{"id": "554"}' AS JSON)
    ->                 )
    -> WHERE `id` = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`, `foo_ids`
    -> FROM `foo_table`;
+----+-----------------------------------------------+
| id | foo_ids                                       |
+----+-----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"id": "432"}, {"id": "433"}, {"id": "554"}] |
+----+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ohWNWvsUHkDkhqpFrFNPpW/3).

**UPDATE**

Can also use the [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator on the conditional:

```sql
mysql> UPDATE `foo_table`
    -> SET `foo_ids` = IF(
    ->                     JSON_TYPE(`foo_ids`) <=> 'ARRAY',
    ->                     `foo_ids`,
    ->                     JSON_ARRAY()
    ->                   ),
    ->     `foo_ids` = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(
    ->                   `foo_ids`,
    ->                   '$',
    ->                   CAST('{"id": "554"}' AS JSON)
    ->                 )
    -> WHERE `id` = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ohWNWvsUHkDkhqpFrFNPpW/4).

Comment: is there any solution for nodejs?