# MySQL interprets my JSON object as a string during an update

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, mysql-5.7

I have a nullable column with the JSON type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn JSON);
```

What I want to do is track events in an array as they come and keep each event in the form of an object inside this array. The desired contents of `mycolumn` after three events have been pushed into the array would be:

```
[
  {"product": ["book"], "subgenre": ["scifi"], "genre": ["fiction"]},
  {"product": ["book"], "subgenre": ["space"], "genre": ["fiction"]},
  {"product": ["book"], "genre": ["romance"]},
]
```

The shape of the objects are irrelevant and unknown (the above are just examples). The only known is that each event will be an object with *at least* one property. Wether that property is an array, object, scalar, string, or null is unknown.

The column will be null initially and my tests revealed that I need to coalesce it into an array or pushing into it will fail.

The closest I got to making this work was:

```
UPDATE
  mytable
SET
  mycolumn = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND (
    COALESCE (mycolumn, '[]'),
    '$',
    (
      '{"product": ["book"], "subgenre": ["scifi"], "genre": ["fiction"], "type": ["newrelease"]}'
    )
  );
```

The problem is that this query interprets the whole object as a string and I end up with an array of strings instead of an array of objects:

```sql
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable;

[
    "{\"product\":[\"book\"],\"subgenre\":[\"scifi\"],\"genre\":[\"fiction\"]}",
    "{\"product\":[\"book\"],\"subgenre\":[\"space\"],\"genre\":[\"fiction\"]}",
    "{\"product\":[\"book\"],\"genre\":[\"romance\"]}"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you want to use something like the `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` function, not `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` function.

The latter evaluates the third argument as a *value*, it doesn't evaluate the third argument as a JSON document.

In the `UPDATE` statement shown, the spurious parens around the third argument (to `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND`) have no meaning. That third argument is just a *value*. The value is a long-ish string that looks like JSON, but in this context, it's just a *string*.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append

---

My suggestion to testing and development of expressions... it is easier and faster to use `SELECT` statements. Once we have expressions that are returning the expected/desired results, then we can move the expression into an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Note that when using `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` you should wrap the new value in array square brackets.

Comment: You linked the 8.0 manual instead of the 5.7 manual ;)  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html

Comment: @Barmar: good point. I didn't give an example; I'll leave it to someone else that wants to develop demonstration expressions, and leave a better answer.   I only answered the question that was asked, the question I inferred was being asked: "*Why is the argument being interpreted as a string and not JSON?*" with a followup on "*How can I change this to get different behavior?*"

Comment: @spencer7593 I interpret almost all SO questions as having an implicit "and how can I fix it". People don't come here just for pedagogical purposes, they want to solve problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
cast('{"product": ["book"], "subgenre": ["scifi"], "genre": ["fiction"], "type": ["newrelease"]}' as json)
```

This is a similar question:

[MySQL append json object to array of json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674489/mysql-append-json-object-to-array-of-json-objects)